# Добавление данных в таблицу MySQL многие-ко-многим

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Как вставить ключи в связывающие таблицы (bookautor, bookrubric) что бы они были такие же как и ключи BookID, AutorID, RubricID? Есть три таблицы autor, book, rubric. И есть еще две связывающие таблицы bookautor и bookrubric:

**Таблица RUBRIC:** `RubricID, RubricName`

**Таблица AUTOR:** `AutorID, FirstName, LastName`

**Таблица BOOK:** `BookID, BookName, book_photo`

**Таблица BOOKAUTOR:** `BookID, AutorID`

**Таблица BOOKRUBRIC:** `BookID, RubricID`

Т.е. я без проблем могу вставить данные в таблицы book, autor и rubric, примерно вот так:

```
public function insert_books_to_db($form_data_book_name){
        return $this->db->insert('book',$form_data_book_name);
    }

    public function insert_autors_to_db($form_data_autor){
        return $this->db->insert('autor',$form_data_autor); 
    }

    public function insert_rubric_to_db($form_data_rubric){
        return $this->db->insert('rubric',$form_data_rubric);   
    }
```

где в аргументе функции я передаю значение полей input и методом insert данные вставляются, но я не могу понять как мне вставлять данные в колонки ID в таблицах bookautor и bookrubric. По плану айдишники таблиц book, autor, rubric должны совпадать с айдишниками в bookautor, bookrubric, чтобы потом используя связь многие-ко-многим делать select через эти две связывающие таблицы примерно вот так:

```
SELECT book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName, rubric.RubricName 
     FROM bookautor
     JOIN book ON book.BookID=bookautor.BookID 
     JOIN autor on autor.AutorID=bookautor.AutorID 
     left join bookrubric on book.BookID=bookrubric.BookID
     LEFT JOIN rubric ON rubric.RubricID=bookrubric.RubricID
```

Какой SQL Insert запрос нужно написать что бы он брал значение BookID, AutorID, RubricID и вставлял эти значения в соответствующие колонки таблиц bookrubric и bookautor что бы можно было сделать выборку? И еще вопрос, должен ли быть в таблицах bookautor и bookrubric установлен primary key и autoincrement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

По моему выполнив этот запрос вы получите последний вставленный id в Базу данных. После получения id вы сможете добавить некую информацию для соединения Ваших таблиц!

Comment: да, так я и сделал уже, только с mysqli